# Button title's text is cut short (iOS)

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a button with a custom text (iconic) in it.  My issue is that the "g" in my title in my button is cut off.  How do I make the g not get chopped off?

[image]

Even when I make the button height very large it sill chops off the g.
[image]

Comment: It has to do with how you are making the button. But you have not shown that, so how can anyone answer?

Comment: Making a button is very self explanatory...I created a button, dragged it to my view.  Set the text to custom with "Material Iconic font" http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/icons.html.  Added the text within the button to it.  Got this...

Comment: WHat happens if you dont use some strange important font rather than the default one? Would not be surprised if it "magically" worked...

Comment: I need the iconic font for the symbol.

Comment: @JoshO'Connor No, you don't. Use an image for the icon and use a normal non-broken font for the text font. That is why I asked you to show what you're doing. Do you want help or not?

Comment: Yes please.  How do I go about doing your method @matt?

Answer (score 11):

This was a very, very simple fix.  All I had to do was press the far right button on the vertical alignment panel in the control section in Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Cool but in my not so humble opinion it would be better to learn about attributed strings in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The icon font is to be used as a source for the icons — not for "normal" letters. Get the icon character from the icon font and the letters from a real font. Like this:

[image]

In that example I've given the button a yellow background just so you can see where it is. You will notice that the "g" descender is not cut off.

Comment: Thanks matt!  Do I programmatically set this up?  I am using the Xcode interface and I can only figure out how to have only one font in a button.  How do I have two fonts?

Comment: You can do it in the button editor: Switch the Title pop-up menu to Attributed. Or you can do it in code with an attributed string (and set the button's `attributedTitle`).

Comment: I just tried it... Xcode is not recogning my custom font.  It is called "MaterialDesignIconicFont" and I dont see it anywhere in the list.  When I highlight the icon, instead of the MaterialDesignIconicFont it is "LastResort"... How do I import a custom font into Attributed?

Comment: I figured it out.  I will post my answer

Comment: Son of a gun, I think you've found a bug! You should report this to Apple (i.e. that custom fonts are not appearing the fonts list when using Attributed in the attributes inspector). I guess you'll have to set the title in code. As I said, you just make an NSAttributedString and set the button's `attributedTitle`. That's what I actually did.